# Merging Lists using iterators

Tags: java, list, iterator

I need to merge two lists of strings in java and I'm not too sure on the best way to do it. I have to use iterators and the compareTo() method. For example...

Example:   L1: A,B,C,D    L2: B,D,F,G      result: A,B,B,C,D,D,F,G

I can assume the input lists are already sorted and i cant use the contains() method. I have some initial checks but the while loop is what im stuck on.

```
public static ListADT<String> merge(ListADT<String> L1,ListADT<String> L2) throws BadListException {
ListADT<String> L3 = new ArrayList<String>;
if(L1 == null || L2 == null) {
    throw new BadListException();
}
Iterator<String> itr1 = new L1.iterator();
Iterator<String> itr2 = new L2.iterator();  
if(L1.size() == 0 && L2.size() == 0) {
    return L3;
}
if(L1.size() == 0 && L2.size() != 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < L2.size(); i++) {
        return L3.add(L2.get(i));
    }
}
if(L2.size() == 0 && L1.size() != 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < L1.size(); i++) {
        return L3.add(L1.get(i));
    }
}
while(itr1.hasNext() || irt2.hasNext()) {
    //merge the lists here?
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly straightforward if you just use variables to hold the current value from each iterator.  This solution assumes your lists do not contain `null`, but it would not be difficult to add null-handling since the lists are sorted.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class IteratorMerge {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"});
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B", "D", "F", "G"});

        System.out.println(merge(list1, list2));
    }

    public static List<String> merge(List<String> L1,List<String> L2) {
        List<String> L3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        Iterator<String> it1 = L1.iterator();
        Iterator<String> it2 = L2.iterator();

        String s1 = it1.hasNext() ? it1.next() : null;
        String s2 = it2.hasNext() ? it2.next() : null;
        while (s1 != null && s2 != null) {
            if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) { // s1 comes before s2
                L3.add(s1);
                s1 = it1.hasNext() ? it1.next() : null;
            }
            else { // s1 and s2 are equal, or s2 comes before s1
                L3.add(s2);
                s2 = it2.hasNext() ? it2.next() : null;
            }
        }

        // There is still at least one element from one of the lists which has not been added
        if (s1 != null) {
            L3.add(s1);
            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                L3.add(it1.next());
            }
        }
        else if (s2 != null) {
            L3.add(s2);
            while (it2.hasNext()) {
                L3.add(it2.next());
            }
        }

        return L3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudocode for the basic algorithm:

```
while(itr1 && itr2)
{
     if(itr1 value < it2 value)
         add itr1 to list
         increment itr1

     else
         add itr2 to list
         increment itr2
}

check if itr1 or itr2 still have more elements
while itr1 or itr2 has more elements, add those elements to the list
```

We know that the lists are sorted, so at each stage, we simply grab the smallest element from each list and add it to the merged list. If, at the end, one of the iterators is exhausted and the other is not, then we can simply iterate through the one which still has elements, appending each element in turn to the merged list.

As you've seen, doing this with Iterators in Java is a bit of a pain as `next()` removes the element. One way of getting around this is to utilize two `Queue`s, one for each Iterator, that store the values from the call to `next()`. You then need to compare the head of each queue, adding the minimum to the merged list and then removing it from its respective `Queue`.

Comment: I think you're unnecessarily complicating the problem by introducing another data structure.  All you need are variables to hold the current value from each list.  See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14805301/44737

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, it is sort of a pain to merge using iterators.  Let's explicitly state why:

- For each step of the merge, you want to *inspect* the first element of **both** sequences, but you only want to *advance* through **one**.
- `Iterator#next()` bundles these *inspect* and *advance* operations into one operation, so it is impossible to inspect the head of both sequences without also advancing through both.

What you need is a way to *peek* at the first element in an `Iterator` without advancing it. If you had this ability, then the merge would look something like:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> merge(Iterator<T> it1, Iterator<T> it2) {
    PeekableIterator<T> seq1 = new PeekableIterator<T>(it1);
    PeekableIterator<T> seq2 = new PeekableIterator<T>(it2);
    List<T> merged = new ArrayList<T>();
    while (seq1.hasNext() && seq2.hasNext()) {
        if (seq1.peekNext().compareTo(seq2.peekNext()) < 0) {
            merged.add(seq1.next());
        } else {
            merged.add(seq2.next());
        }
    }
    while (seq1.hasNext()) {
        merged.add(seq1.next());
    }
    while (seq2.hasNext()) {
        merged.add(seq2.next());
    }
    return merged;
}
```

And it turns out that it is not too difficult to create this `PeekableIterator`!  You just need to keep track of whether or not you currently have a peeked element, and what that element is.

```
public class PeekableIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Iterator<T> backing;
    private boolean havePeek = false;
    private T peek;

    public PeekableIterator(Iterator<T> backing) {
        this.backing = backing;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return havePeek || backing.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (havePeek) {
            havePeek = false;
            return peek;
        } else {
            return backing.next();
        }
    }

    public T peekNext() {
        if (!havePeek) {
            peek = backing.next();
            havePeek = true;
        }
        return peek;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I didn't notice the comment above referring to the `PeekingIterator` in Google's Guava library, which is more or less the same as the `PeekableIterator` here.  If you have access to third party libraries, this would certainly be preferable to rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to manage merging of an empty list with a non empty one as a special case, just loop until at least one of the iterators is valid and do your work directly there:

```
public static ListADT<String> merge(ListADT<String> L1,ListADT<String> L2) throws BadListException {
  ListADT<String> L3 = new ArrayList<String>;

  Iterator<String> itr1 = new L1.iterator(), itr2 = new L2.iterator();

  while (itr1.hasNext() || itr2.hasNext()) {
    if (!itr1.hasNext())
      L3.add(itr2.next());
    else if (!itr2.hasNext())
      L3.add(itr1.next());
    else {
      String s1 = peek from itr1
      String s2 = peek from itr2;

      if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) {
        L3.add(itr1.next());
        L3.add(itr2.next());
      }
      else {
        L3.add(itr2.next());
        L3.add(itr1.next())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `L3.add(s1); L3.add(s2);` the next item in the `L1` could be less than `s2`, yet you have already added `s2` to the output! The merging loop needs to advance only one, not both iterators, per loop iteration. Consider merging `{1,2}` and `{3}`. Your algorithm will produce `{1, 3, 2}`, because it would add `1` and then `3` in the same iteration, before getting a chance to look at `2`.

Comment: Yes, wrote by impulse without noticing. Actually a `Iterator<E>` has no way to fetch an element without advancing the iterator IIRC. This completely defeats the purpose of using an iterator though.

Comment: my next question is how do i get the next value without advancing the iterator so i can compareTo() the other value from the other list.

Comment: @user1874239 See my answer for an idea as to how you can do this with Iterators in Java.

Comment: You simply can't. JDK iterators are unfortunately limited. A solution would be to use for example a `PeekingIterator` from Guava library which is able to do it. Take a look here: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html

Comment: @user1874239, as Jack said, you cannot get the next value without advancing the cursor.  If you use a ListIterator instead of an Iterator, you can use ListIterator.previous() to move the cursor to the previous element.  So a peek() would essentially be next() followed by previous().  However, you could just save the current value in a variable each time next() is called.

Answer (score 0):

public class MergeIterator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    s1.add("a");
    s1.add("z");
    s1.add("b");
    s1.add("k");
    s1.add("c");
    Collections.sort(s1);
    List<String> s2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    s2.add("p");
    s2.add("a");
    s2.add("d");
    s2.add("n");
    s2.add("m");
    Collections.sort(s2);
    Iterator<String> it1 = s1.iterator();
    // sortIterator(it1);
    Iterator<String> it2 = s2.iterator();
    System.out.println();
    combine(it1, it2);
}

private static Iterator<String> combine(Iterator<String> it1,
        Iterator<String> it2) {
    Iterator<String> it3 = null;
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    String s1 = null, s2 = null;
    while (it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext()) { //line 1

    s1 = (s1 == null ? (it1.hasNext() ? it1.next() : null) : s1); //line 2 
    s2 = (s2 == null ? (it2.hasNext() ? it2.next() : null) : s2); // line 3
        if (s1 != null && s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) { // line 4
            l1.add(s1);
            s1 = null;
        } else {
            l1.add(s2);
            s2 = null;
        }

    }
    it3 = l1.iterator();
    return it3;
}
```

}

Comment: @Idos I assume you what explanation to combine method. it1 & it2 is a sorted array. Now jump on line 1 which i commented on code it will run until my  ant iterator (it1 or it2) has value in it. line 2 : It will check if s1 is null or not if yes will assign value for it1 and increment the pointer inside the it1 to next element if s1 in not null it will assign the same value which s1 is having vice versa for line 3. Jump on line 4 : It is comparing whether value in s1 is smaller then s1 then add s1 to list l1 else add s2 to l1. That's it.

Comment: @Idos Example : itr1 = {a,c} ; itr2 = {b,d} ;<br/>  cycle 1 s1 = a s2 = b  a<b li.add(s1) s1= null ; <br/> cycle2 s1=c s2 = b li.add(s2) s2 = null ;<br/> cycle 3  s1=c s2 = d c < d li.add(s1) <br/> cycle4 s1 = null s2 = d li.add(s2)